# Text Input Source Services gives Mach-O Linker error for architecture x86_64?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm attempting to use Text Input Source Services to detect the current keyboard layout:

```
TISInputSourceRef source = TISCopyCurrentKeyboardInputSource(); //Mach-O Linker Error
NSLog(@"languages: %@", TISGetInputSourceProperty(source, kTISPropertyInputSourceLanguages));
NSLog(@"localized name: %@", TISGetInputSourceProperty(source, kTISPropertyLocalizedName));
```

Which is a ('modern') carbon function I reference with: `#import <Carbon/Carbon.h>`

Docs: (don't mention anything about x86 vs. x64)
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/TextFonts/Reference/TextInputSourcesReference/Reference/reference.html

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_TISCopyCurrentKeyboardInputSource", referenced from:
      -[XXXFILE YYYEVENT:] in ZZZPROJECT.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Is there a reason I can't use TIS with the `x86_64` compiler?

Comment: I’ve just tested your code and it built fine (10.7 SDK, x86_64). Are you sure you’re linking the Carbon framework? Just `#import`ing the header file is not enough.

Comment: What else would I have to do? The xcode auto-complete functionality is suggesting "TISCopyCurrentKeyboardInputSource()" and such so I thought that meant I was successfully using them...

Comment: In Xcode 4, select your project in the tree view in the left pane, then select your target, choose Summary, click + in Linked Frameworks and Libraries, select Carbon.framework, click Add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Bavarious's comment on the qusetion, added the Carbon.framework rather than just `#include`ing it. Answer with a real `Stack Overflow Answer` and I will upvote it!

Comment: No, adding Carbon.framework was the part which solved the problem. Try  using `#import` and with Carbon.framework added.

Comment: Hmm, could have sworn that I changed it to `include` first without adding the framework and it worked fine. Guess not. Answer clarified.

Comment: He didn't answer with an Answer :/

Comment: @cks I was waiting for you to confirm that linking Carbon was the problem! It’s okay for you to answer and accept your own answer, though. Go ahead.